# Decode function with like keyword in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, decode, sql-like

I wrote the following SQL query with your help to generate a report.

```
SELECT ins.ins_name, ins.ins, crdi.ct, crdi.bn,
       sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'PO', 1, 0)) POCount,
       sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'CN', 1, 0)) CNCount
  FROM crdh, crdi, ins
 WHERE crdh.crd_st IN ('PO','CN')
   AND crdi.bn IN (select unique bn from crdh)
   AND crdh.bn = crdi.bn
   AND crdi.ins = ins.ins
 GROUP BY ins.ins, crdi.bn, ins.ins_name, crdi.ct
 ORDER BY ins.ins, crdi.bn;
```

Now I have to modify this query so that I can add some new fields in this report. But the problem is I need to use `LIKE` keyword. There is field called cardh.grp_id which looks like `'A0100'` and I need to take the count `'A%'`, `'%01%'` and `'%00'` using `LIKE` keyword.

So I just want to know how can I use `sum(DECODE(cardh.grp_id like.....))`

Comment: you will need to change your query to use `CASE` instead of `LIKE` to do this.